# How to show a popup window using mass action on sales order grid - Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2

I have created a new mass action on admin's sales order on Magento 2.2.4.
Now, I want a popup window to be shown whenever I click on the action button. 
How can I achieve this? Any workaround will me much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you share a [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with action button and popup?

Comment: This is what I am looking for. I don't have any code that creates a popup. I have just created a massaction in the sales order grid in admin view. I intend to use this massaction to create a popup instead of redirecting me to the controller's url path.